# output contents of dict to specified text format

Tags: python, dictionary, f-string

I have a dictionary with the following information

```
dict = {'key1':['1:2','2:3','3:4'], 'key2':['4:5','5:6']}
```

I need to out put this to a text file using the following format, the key and its values are to be commar seperated, with no '' quotation marks, each key and its values are to be separated by a new line

```
key1,1:2,2:3,3:4
key2,4:5,5:6
```

If i use the following code i do not get the intended output, any help would be appreciated

```
with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
     f.writelines(f'{k},{v}\n'for k,v in dict .items())
```

Comment: instead `'{v}'` use `{','.join(v)}` - and you might need to check the \n usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `join` as Patrick says:

```py
d = {'key1':['1:2','2:3','3:4'], 'key2':['4:5','5:6']}

for k,v in d.items():
    print(f'{k},{",".join(v)}')

#or writing to a file:
with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
     f.writelines(f'{k},{",".join(v)}\n' for k,v in d.items())
```

Output as requested